# Split a dataframe into new dataframes of overlapping columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, intersection

I have a dataframe with many hundreds of columns and as many rows. The first column contains an ID. All following columns represent an observation. These have the values 1 or 0. Now I want to divide the dataframe into new dataframes that contain only those columns that are overlapping. Where do I start here? Sorry, I have no idea...

```
df_input <- structure(list(
  a <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
  b <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  c <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  d <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  e <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  f <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("id", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
```

In my example, two dataframes would need to be created. One dataframe for column A, because it has no overlap with other columns. A second dataframe for all other columns, since they have no overlapps with each other in different rows.

Comment: @IRTFM Thanks for the tip. I have updated this. My English is not so clean that causes confusion ;-)

Comment: (1) you have no column "A", you have columns `b` through `f` and `id`. (2) Don't do `list(a <- c(..), b <- c(..))`, it is verifiably not doing what you expect. For example, try `list(a<-1,b<-2)` and see that it is a list with no names; now look and see that you now have two variables in your global named `a` and `b`. While `<-` and `=` are effectively synonymous for object assignment, one can *only* use `=` when naming objects passed to `list` (and `data.frame`, though it uses non-standard evaluation and masks the problem).

Comment: (3) it sounds like a bit of anti-clustering, which is certainly a challenging topic. You mention. It sounds like minimization of differences, which scales rather poorly. It's also under-defined a bit: what happens after this first branch, where you separate the `b` column from the others; do you intend to rerun the splitting algorithm on the two new sub-frames?

Comment: I also think there are situations that would not be separable using this logic. Take the three columns defined by `b <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    c <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    d <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)`  c and d are rowwise not equal anywhere but they both have rows where they are "==" to b.  So I think you really do need to explain the purposes for this exercise so that a principled solution can be defined on alternate grounds.

Comment: What about `split(df_input, rowSums(df_input[-1]))`?